# UIMA Ruta matching features using regular expression

Tags: uima, ruta

I've been able to use Ruta with great success to create annotations using the RegExpRule and REGEXP. However, I've run into a slight block. I have annotations created by another engine that assign String features that are essentially comments.

```
STRING featureComment;
OtherEngineAnnotation{GETFEATURE("comment", featureComment)};
//featureComment = "some comment like text"
```

Because the feature values might not occur in the document I can't use the RegExpRules to annotate the feature value. I wanted to be able to search the `featureComment` using as an example the regular expression:

```
like\stext$
```

Based on my reading of the documentation this doesn't seem possible. I was wondering if there is another way this can be done?

Essentially can a regex pattern be checked against a Ruta `STRING`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [REGEXP](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.conditions.regexp) condition can also work on variables or feature values, an optional first argument A rule could look like:

```
OtherEngineAnnotation{REGEXP(OtherEngineAnnotation.comment, "like\\stext$")};
```

or

```
o:OtherEngineAnnotation{REGEXP(o.comment, "like\\stext$")};
```

Please mind the verison of UIMA Ruta. You need probably at least UIMA Ruta 2.5.0.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: I've found that this wouldn't match on the example when the value of the feature is "some comment like text" since it isn't a full match almost as if a `^` and `$` are appended to the regex pattern. Is there a way around this besides adding `.*` to the pattern?

Comment: Unfortunately not. REGEXP uses only `matches()`. There is no `find()` yet.